# Python and environment variables

Tags: python, subprocess

In the following code snippet (meant to work in an init.d environment) I would like to execute test.ClassPath. However, I'm having trouble setting and passing the CLASSPATH environment variable as defined in the user's .bashrc.

Here is the source of my frustration:

- When the below script is run in use mode, it prints out the CLASSPATH OK (from $HOME/.bashrc)
- when I run it as root, it also displays CLASSPATH fine (I've set up /etc/bash.bashrc with CLASSPATH)
- BUT when I do "sudo script.py" (to simulate what happens at init.d startup time), the CLASSPATH is missing !!

The CLASSPATH is quite large, so I'd like to read it from a file .. say $HOME/.classpath

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os.path as osp
import os

user = "USERNAME"
logDir = "/home/USERNAME/temp/"
print os.environ["HOME"]

if "CLASSPATH" in os.environ:
        print os.environ["CLASSPATH"]
else:
        print "Missing CLASSPATH"
procLog = open(osp.join(logDir, 'test.log'), 'w')
cmdStr = 'sudo -u %s -i java  test.ClassPath'%(user, ) # run in user
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdStr, shell=True, bufsize=0, stderr=procLog, stdout=procLog)
procLog.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put `source ~/.bashrc` before starting your python script to get the environment variables set.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` will not pass environment variables by default.  From the man page:

```
   By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes
   commands to be executed with a minimal environment containing
   TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER and USERNAME in
   addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by
   the env_check and env_keep options.  This is effectively a
   whitelist for environment variables.
```

There are a few ways of addressing this.

1. You can edit `/etc/sudoers` to explicitly pass the `CLASSPATH`
   variable using the `env_keep` configuration directive.  That might
   look something like:

   ```
   Defaults env_keep += "CLASSPATH"
   ```
2. You can run your command using the `env` command, which lets you set the environment explicitly.  A typical command line invocation might look like this:

   ```
   sudo env CLASSPATH=/path1:/path2 java test.ClassPath
   ```

The obvious advantage to option (2) is that it doesn't require mucking about with the `sudoers` configuration.

Comment: I sudo while calling the script to simulate  what happens when init.d calls this script. So, how can I apply this idea at init.d time?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I've suggested how to make your existing script work using the `env` command.  I *think* this will do what you want.  If that doesn't meet your requirements, please update your question (rather than turning this into a giant comment thread) to indicate how the behavior you want differs from the behavior you get using this suggestion.