# Get java version number from python

Tags: python, bash, sed, grep, cut

I need to get the java version number, for example "1.5", from python (or bash).

I would use:

```
os.system('java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version" | cut -d "\\\"" -f 2')
```

But that returns 1.5.0_30

It needs to be compatible if the number changes to "1.10" for example.

I would like to use cut or grep or even sed.
It should be in one line.

Comment: *"It needs to be compatible"* - with what? What are you actually trying to achieve? *"It should be in one line"* - why?

Comment: compatible with newer java versions. And in one line to keep the code clean.

Comment: Why do you think that it will break with e.g. `"1.10"`? You're running a terminal command via `os.system`, I think *"clean"* has been and gone...

Comment: @jteichert one-liners aren't necessarily clean code.

Comment: @fedorqui i need just the major and minor version. The reason is, that this has to go into the build function of a waf script. That only accepts major.minor version (at least it didnt work just now when I used 1.5.0)
`bld(features = 'javac jar', compat = '1.5', ... )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering an output like this:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

You can get the version number with `awk` like this:

```
$ java -version 2>&1 | awk -F[\"_] 'NR==1{print $2}'
1.8.0
```

Or, if you just want the first two `.`-separated digits:

```
$ java -version 2>&1 | awk -F[\"\.] -v OFS=. 'NR==1{print $2,$3}'
1.8
```

Here, `awk` sets the field separator to either `"` or `_` (or `.`), so that the line is sliced in pieces. Then, it prints the 2nd field on the first line (indicated by `NR==1`). By setting `OFS` we indicate what is the output field separator, so that saying `print $2, $3` prints the 2nd field followed by the 3rd one with a `.` in between.

To use it in Python you need to escape properly:

```
>>> os.system('java -version 2>&1 | awk -F[\\\"_] \'NR==1{print $2}\'')
1.8.0
>>> os.system('java -version 2>&1 | awk -F[\\\"\.] -v OFS=. \'NR==1{print $2,$3}\'')
1.8
```

Comment: You can't capture the child's output with `os.system()`, so this method is less practical than others.

Comment: @mhawke Not sure why child's output may be necessary here. Also, as I said below Peter Wood's answer, I also thing his answer is superior since it uses Python entirely.

Comment: Surely the child's output is necessary if you actually want to do anything with the version number obtained.

Comment: You really want to avoid `os.system()` and Awk here. The `subprocess` answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 21):

The Java runtime seems to send the version information to the stderr. You can get at this using Python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) module:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> version = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

>>> print version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

You can get the version out with a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '\"(\d+\.\d+).*\"'

>>> print re.search(pattern, version).groups()[0]
1.7
```

If you are using a pre-2.7 version of Python, see this question: [subprocess.check_output() doesn't seem to exist (Python 2.6.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814970/subprocess-check-output-doesnt-seem-to-exist-python-2-6-5)

Comment: very nice one! I learnt a lot from it, better than my calling to external `awk`.

Comment: This is the right answer. Keep the subprocess as simple as possible (just get the output from `java`), and process the resulting string in Python.

Comment: thanks, one remark: subprocess only worked when I replaced `check_output` with `check_call`.
I have python 2.6 installed.

Comment: @jteichert I've updated the answer with a link to [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814970/subprocess-check-output-doesnt-seem-to-exist-python-2-6-5) about missing `check_output`, pre-2.7.

Comment: @PeterWood ah thank you very much for the workaround for pre 2.7 versions of python.

Comment: Does subprocess.Popen use another environment than my current shell?
I want to use the java version that i specified with my JAVA_HOME path (in .bashrc). But thats another one than I am getting with this command.

Comment: @jteichert See [Python and environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885251/python-and-environment-variables).

Comment: @jteichert Also, [How to use the bash shell with Python's subprocess module instead of /bin/sh](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/04/how-use-bash-shell-python-subprocess-instead-binsh/).

Comment: If you have set `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` env variable then java will print the options before the actual result, which might break your regex later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture the command's output with `os.system()`. Instead, use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> java_version = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>>> java_version
'openjdk version "1.8.0_51"\nOpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)\nOpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)\n'
```

Now that you can collect the command output, you can extract the version number using Python, rather than piping through other commands (which, incidentally, would require use of the less secure `shell=True` argument to `check_output`).

```
>>> version_number = java_version.splitlines()[0].split()[-1].strip('"')
>>> major, minor, _ = version_number.split('.')
>>> print 'Major: {}, Minor: {}'.format(major, minor)
Major: 1, Minor: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could let grep handle a regular expression:

```
java -version 2>&1 | grep -Eow '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post, but if someone needs it:

```
import subprocess
import re

javaPath = 'C:/.../java.exe'

javaInfo = subprocess.check_output(javaPath + ' -version', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
javaVersion = re.search(r'"[0-9\._]*"', javaInfo.decode().split("\r")[0]).group().replace('"', '')

print(javaVersion)
```

Answer (score 0):

python

```
import os;

os.system("java -version 2>&1 | grep 'version' 2>&1 | awk -F\\\" '{ split($2,a,\".\"); print a[1]\".\"a[2]}'");

xxx=os.popen("java -version 2>&1 | grep 'version' 2>&1 | awk -F\\\" '{ split($2,a,\".\"); print a[1]\".\"a[2]}'").read();

print xxx
1.8
```